# What size gaskets/washers do I order to repair this frost proof/free outdoor faucet? (Dripping from the spout)

Tags: plumbing, repair, hardware, leaks, outdoorfaucet

UPDATE: I found it!  Its a Boshart 0865P-080 (080 is for the 8" size) I will add a screenshot of the info sheet I found online, and another photo of the faucets handwheel front, which is where the model number was. (I missed it before)

I have added Boshart's website and a link to this particular product's  page is [here](https://boshart.com/product/pex-x-ght-nitrile-rubber-with-self-draining-vacuum-breaker-leaded/?attribute_pa_tube_length=8-0000).

Unfortunately, I still can't seem to find the sizes of the packing/O-rings though, but thought I would share the brand in case anyone else found this post through a search, like I found other types posted on this site.

[image: Info Sheet - Boshart 0865P-080]

[image: Handwheel with model numer - Boshart 0865P-080]

[image: Boshart 0865P-080]

---

Original Post:
After a bit of googling, it looks like the most common repair for "dripping from the spout" is a damaged gasket. So we will need to replace the washers in our dripping frost proof faucet. (If we are lucky, that's all we will need to do!)

Unfortunately, I am assuming it is because we stupidly left the hose attached over winter. (Or someone tightened it to hard!)

Living on Vancouver Island (here in Canada), we do freeze up occasionally, but usually don't get temperatures as low as we did this winter. I believe we got as low, (or lower than) -15 this winter. (Winter of 2021-22)

Other than blowing out the irrigation, we don't usually worry that much about winterization. (And in our old homes, we have never had these "frost free" type of outdoor faucets before either.)

Anyway, lesson learned. Now I need to order some new washers etc, but have no idea what sizes to order. I was hoping to pre-order before taking apart the faucet, because getting into the crawlspace to turn off the water to that faucet will be a real P.I.T.A. And turning off the water to the whole house for very long, will cause a riot. (Teenagers!)

So I was hoping to have the parts all ready to go, so we only have to cut the water once. Is that even possible?

Anyway. The faucet doesn't have a brand name on it, but has the markings "ASSE" (as in "this is a real pain in the..."), the numbers "1019A", a letter "C" to the left of a crest of arms-like shape, with a diagonal banner inside of it. Unfortunately, I can't make out the letters inside of it. One the other side of the crest is a backwards letter "R",and on the tap spout there is the letters "EA".

Better yet...I will try to attach a photo! Lol [image: Dripping faucet - Boshart 0865P-080]

This is a fairly new home, I believe it was built around 2011.

Thank you! Any help that you can offer, is greatly appreciated. Obviously I am the furthest thing from a plumber! But unfortunately, I can't afford a huge water bill, ...OR a plumber, so I am going to try doing it myself!

Comment: Water gets larger when it freezes. That is why freeze damage happens.  Gaskets are resilient and I wouldn't expect them to take freeze damage.  Metal parts, on the other hand...

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a Question & Answer forum and that we like questions to have answers. Since you found an answer, please put it down below in the box marked "Your Answer" - self answers are not only acceptable, they're encouraged! This will make it easier for others with this issue to find questions with answers - as it stands, this appears to be a question without any answer at all and future readers would think it's not going to help them.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's only partly answered for me, I guess. I still need to know what kind of washers I need to order. :) (I was hoping someone out there had the same kind of faucet.) I'm very sorry if I am using this forum wrong. It is the first time I have used it. I happened across it when googling for an answer.